# How to get a different proxy on every thread with requests?

Tags: python, proxy

I'm kinda stuck with my project... I'm making this project to learn requests and how to work with threads. My program is working fine for viewing a specific URL but it needs to visit the URL with a different proxy. Like when I have 200 threads I want it to visit the URL with a different proxy on every thread. Here is my code so far:

```
import time
import threading
import requests


def get_settings():
    total_viewers = input("Please enter the total viewers: ")
    to_watch = input("Please enter the url to watch: ")
    time_to_watch = input("Please enter total time to watch: ")
    start_viewer_threads(total_viewers, to_watch, time_to_watch)


def start_viewer(to_watch, time_to_watch):
    proxies = {
       "http": "http://ip:port"
       "https": "https://ip:port"
       "ftp": "ftp://ip:port"
    }
    viewer_session = requests.Session()
    viewer_request = viewer_session.get(to_watch, proxies=proxies)
    print(viewer_request.url)
    print("Starting to watch: " + to_watch)
    time.sleep(int(time_to_watch))
    print(viewer_request.url)


def start_viewer_threads(total_viewers, to_watch, time_to_watch):
    threads = []
    for _ in range(int(total_viewers)):
        t = threading.Thread(target=start_viewer, args=[to_watch, time_to_watch])
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


get_settings()
```

I thought of the idea to nest the loop in start_viewer_threads in another for loop. I have no idea how to change it everytime it starts a new thread. I would like to have a .txt file where the proxies are stored and read it from there. You don't need to give me the whole code but please get me in the right direction. Do I need to nest the other loop?

Comment: The threading library is rather low level, it might be worth using a different tool.

Comment: @AMC You suggest multiprocessing? But my question was not if the threading library is low level but how to rotate proxies and have a different one on every thread. Thanks for helping.

Comment: _You suggest multiprocessing?_ No, what I had in mind were some higher level libraries like concurrent.futures, aiohttp, etc.  As an aside, I don't think using a requests Session in the `start_viewer` function accomplishes much, since you only make a single request.